# Grails multiple databases

Tags: grails

how can we write queries on 2 databases .

I installed datasources plugin and domain classes are :

```
class Organization {
    long id
    long company_id
    String name

    static mapping = {
        version false
        table 'organization_'
        id column : 'organizationId'
        company_id column : 'companyId'
        name column : 'name'
    }
}
```

---

```
class Assoc {
    Integer id
    Integer association_id
    Integer organization_id


    static mapping = {
        version false
        table 'assoc'
        id column : 'ASSOC_ID'
        association_id column : 'ASSOCIATION_ID'
        organization_id column : 'ORGANIZATION_ID'
    }
}
```

this is working :

```
def org = Organization.list()
def assoc = Assoc.list()
```

and this is not working :

```
def query = Organization.executeQuery("SELECT o.name as name, o.id FROM Organization o WHERE o.id IN (SELECT a.organization_id FROM Assoc a )")
```

error :

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Assoc is not mapped
>   [SELECT o.name as name, o.id FROM org.com.domain.Organization o WHERE
>   o.id IN (SELECT a.organization_id FROM AssocOrg a )]

How can we connect with 2 databases using single query ?

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to split it into two queries, get the ids first and use those in the primary query. The plugin partitions your domain classes each into their own separate SessionFactory, so you can't join in Hibernate.

Comment: hi burt , My bad.I didn't understand "get the ids first and use those in the primary query". Is it should we use in loop ?. could you please explain with small example . thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant: def organizationIds = Assoc.executeQuery("SELECT a.organization_id FROM Assoc a"); def query = Organization.executeQuery("SELECT o.name as name, o.id FROM Organization o WHERE o.id IN (:ids)", [ids: organizationIds]) (apologies for crappy comment formatting)

Comment: Thanks Burt for giving solution .

Comment: I have a similar scenario. I am to read data from two databases and display on the page. The reading from the 2 databases happen in the same sql. The query returns around 3 columns from each database based on a where clause. How do I put my code in my application in this scenario? Thoughts?